# Whether to use a verbal or a deverbal noun as a modifier?

Tags: grammar, nouns

Which is more grammatically correct:

`an XXX-inhibiting drug`, or
`an XXX inhibitor drug`?

It would seem to me that the use of the verbal noun ("inhibiting") as a modifier is more grammatically acceptable than the deverbal form ("inhibitor"). I say this based on the observation that verbal nouns are generally more grammatically flexible since they retain verbal characteristics. However, I most often see cases of ["inhibitor drug"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22inhibitor%20drug%22) in the literature than instances of ["inhibiting drug"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22inhibiting%20drug%22).

Comment: Both the forms are used depending on the context. Where the reference is to, or the emphasis is on, the action, we would use the verbal modifier ('*inhibiting drug*'); where we are talking mainly about the object (drug) with its action or the nature of its action being secondary or incidental to the context, we would use the non-verbal modifier ('*inhibitor drug*').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, though they do of course have different structures, as you note.

But they do different jobs.

- The *-ing* structure is a ***description***; it describes the salient feature of the drug: it inhibits `XXX`. Nothing more is said about any other effects, side-effects, or contraindications of the drug, nor indeed about what kind of drug it is or just **how** it inhibits `XXX`. All we know is that one generic fact.
- The *-or* structure, on the other hand, is a ***name***; it identifies the drug as a member of a named class of drugs, *the `XXX` inhibitor drugs*, which can be expected to have similar properties, and to act in similar biochemical ways to inhibit `XXX`, in varying degrees, and with varying side effects.

The choice of use depends on what is to be implied by the term.